# Remove the wishlist and shoppingcart tab from customer edit in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, adminhtml, overrides, wishlist

`config.xml`

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <config>
        <modules>
           <Ndot_Customer>
               <version>1.0</version>
           </Ndot_Customer>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                        <customer_edit_tabs>Ndot_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

`Tabs.php`

```
    <?php

    class Ndot_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('customer_info_tabs');
            $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
            $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Information'));
        }

        protected function _beforeToHtml() {
    /*
            if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId()) {
                $this->addTab('view', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer View'),
                    'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view')->toHtml(),
                    'active'    => true
                ));
            }
    */
            $this->addTab('account', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Account Information'),
                'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_account')->initForm()->toHtml(),
                'active'    => Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId() ? false : true
            ));

            $this->addTab('addresses', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Addresses'),
                'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_addresses')->initForm()->toHtml(),
            ));


            // load: Orders, Shopping Cart, Wishlist, Product Reviews, Product Tags - with ajax

            if (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId()) {

                if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
                    $this->addTab('orders', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders'),
                        'class'     => 'ajax',
                        'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/orders', array('_current' => true)),
                     ));
                }

                //$this->addTab('cart', array(
                //    'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shopping Cart'),
                //    'class'     => 'ajax',
                //    'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/carts', array('_current' => true)),
                //));

                /*$this->addTab('wishlist', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wishlist'),
                    'class'     => 'ajax',
                    'url'       => $this->getUrl('//wishlist', array('_current' => true)),
                )); */

                if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('newsletter/subscriber')) {
                    $this->addTab('newsletter', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Newsletter'),
                        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_newsletter')->initForm()->toHtml()
                    ));
                }

                if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/reviews_ratings')) {
                    $this->addTab('reviews', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Product Reviews'),
                        'class'     => 'ajax',
                        'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/productReviews', array('_current' => true)),
                    ));
                }

                if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/tag')) {
                    $this->addTab('tags', array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Product Tags'),
                        'class'     => 'ajax',
                        'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/productTags', array('_current' => true)),
                    ));
                }
            }

            $this->_updateActiveTab();
            Varien_Profiler::stop('customer/tabs');
            return parent::_beforeToHtml();
        }

        protected function _updateActiveTab()
        {
            $tabId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('tab');
            if( $tabId ) {
                $tabId = preg_replace("#{$this->getId()}_#", '', $tabId);
                if($tabId) {
                    $this->setActiveTab($tabId);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

`Ndot_Customer.xml`

```
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Ndot_Customer>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Ndot_Customer>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

But when i remove the wishlist and shoppingcart from the extended file(`Ndot_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs` ), the tab is not removing. only when I change the core file(`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs`) its working.

Share your answer to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line in your code

```
return parent::_beforeToHtml();
```

Calling this, will call the original method from the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs` that adds again the tabs you remove in your code.
You can replace this line with

```
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::_beforeToHtml();
```

This should work but it's not very OOP, because you call a method that's not static as a static one.
The clean way to do it would be to replace the line I mentioned above with:

```
    if ($activeTab = $this->getRequest()->getParam('active_tab')) {
        $this->setActiveTab($activeTab);
    } elseif ($activeTabId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getActiveTabId()) {
        $this->_setActiveTab($activeTabId);
    }

    $_new = array();
    foreach( $this->_tabs  as $key => $tab ) {
        foreach( $this->_tabs  as $k => $t ) {
            if( $t->getAfter() == $key ) {
                $_new[$key] = $tab;
                $_new[$k] = $t;
            } else {
                if( !$tab->getAfter() || !in_array($tab->getAfter(), array_keys($this->_tabs)) ) {
                    $_new[$key] = $tab;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_tabs = $_new;
    unset($_new);

    $this->assign('tabs', $this->_tabs);
    return $this;
```

which is the code from the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::_beforeToHtml()` method.